# Uniqueness of a topology given the closed sets

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to demonstrate that given a collection $\mathscr{C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ verifying

> 1. $\emptyset, X \in \mathscr{C}$
> 2. $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}, C_i \in \mathscr{C} \Rightarrow \bigcap_{i\in I} \in \mathscr{C}$
> 3. $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^n, C_i \in \mathscr{C} \Rightarrow \bigcup_{i=1}^n \in \mathscr{C}$

Then exists a topology $\tau$ over $X$ whose closed sets are $\mathscr{C}$ and it's unique.

My problem is the uniqueness. This is what I tried:
If there are two topologies $\tau_1, \tau_2$ over $X$ satisfying 1, 2, 3, then

$O \in \tau_1 \Leftrightarrow X\setminus O \in \mathscr{C} \Leftrightarrow X\setminus (X\setminus O) \in \tau_2 \Leftrightarrow O \in \tau_2$
Hence $\tau_1 = \tau_2$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: That looks fine to me. I think it might be a little redundant. As soon as you know that $X - O \in \mathcal{C}$, you should be able to conclude that $O \in \tau_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I'll correct it.

Comment: It's an OK proof, IMHO.

Comment: IMHO? What does it mean?

Comment: In my humble opinion.